# read, edit & save config files (php)

Tags: php, file-manipulation

I have two **configuration files**. One is **ini** one is **php**. They look like below. I need to **update the database file name** but the rest of the files must be **unchanged**. Any idea how to do so?

config.ini

```
; Turning Debugging on
[test]
developer = true

; Production site configuration data
[production]
database.params.dbname   = /var/lib/firebird/data/radek_db.gdb
```

and setting.php

```
<?php
/**
The settings file
*/

#This will be done automatically if u want to override it uncomment the next line few lines
/*
    $Path   = 'mainline';

#Database to connect to:
    $Database        =       "radek_db";
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you read the file to a string with file_get_contents(), do a str_replace() or preg_replace() on it, and then save over it with file_put_contents()?

I'd link those all to the documentation, but I don't have the reputation to make more than one link...

**EDIT**: If all you know is the name of the option, you can use [preg_match](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to find the option name with a regexp (something like `'/^database\.params\.dbname = (.*)$/'`) and then do a str_replace on the name you find.

Something like this:

```
$file = file_get_contents('/path/to/config/file');
$matches = array();
preg_match('/^database\.params\.dbname = (.*)$/', $file, $matches);
$file = str_replace($matches[1], $new_value, $file);
file_put_contents('/path/to/config/file', $file);
```

Comment: more than string replace I need to find the option and then replace it's value. Not sure if it could be done this way

Comment: Ahhh--I was assuming you knew what the current setting on the option to change was. I am amending my answer appropriately.

Comment: thank you @Mickey and the last thing would be to search only within particular section :-)

Answer (score 1):

For reading ini files, there's [`parse_ini_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php). For the rest, you'll have to write a simple script for that purpose... or use [`sed`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed).

Comment: I read somewhere that `parse_ini_file` ignores comments. I need to save the file as it was.